# Cross checking camel ftp/sftp authentication before starting route

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-ftp

Can I check if Camel FTP route is valid or authentication successful before starting the route?

If the password is incorrect the endpoint will not connect and will not consume, but it only get to know after starting of route.

Is there any way to hit the endpoint to check authentication before start of the route?

Comment: I guess you would have to still hit the endpoint (maybe on another "test" route) and catch any exception?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no such check.

However there is `ComponentVerifierExtension` which allows to build a verifier that can check login credentials. We have done this for a number of Camel components such as aws, salesforce, http, etc.

But there is no implementation for camel-ftp for this.